# Grails dependencies or Maven

Tags: grails, maven-2, ivy, dependency-management, springsource

I'm using STS latest version (2.7) and latest grails as well. After I created a freshly grails project in STS it freezes in the updating grails dependencies for a long time and it comes out as a timeout error. And it follows by some GroovyObject error, but the project still runs fine in command-line. So I ditched STS for refreshing dependencies, and I included the dependency in BuildConfig.groovy and use `grails compile` but I still got ClassNotFound error when compiling, it's like grails didn't pick up the Ivy CLASSPATH. So, I'm thinking of changing it to Maven to resolve any dependencies.

My question would be which one is better and integrated seamlessly in STS or Eclipse?, but I still want to use grails commands, not maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project is just a grails project - use grails dependencies.

I've experience with mavenized grails project, and plain grails project. First is good when you have multimodule project, and only one of them is grails module. At this case you'll lost all grails commands, you need to use commands like `mvn grails:run-app` and it's complicated thing to pass arguments into commands :(

Comment: Mine is grails + Java project, I use pure java for the back-end, and grails for the front-end.